# Segmentation Fault with g++ in Linux Ubuntu, but not with g++/MingW in Windows, when printing a char string in C++

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, g++, mingw

I have a program, which:

1. Creates an array of 3 `char` pointers, `char *z_str[3];`.
2. Allocates dynamic memory objects of type `char` and assign the returned pointers to these `char` pointers.
3. Prompt the user for giving Input strings.
4. Print the provided strings.

---

The source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *z_str[3];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        z_str[i] = new char [30];
        if(z_str[i] == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Memory for String " << i+1 << " could not be allocated!" << endl;
            cout << "Program terminates.";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Please input the first string [max.29 characters]:" << endl;
    cin >> z_str[0]; 
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please input the second string [max.29 characters]:" << endl;
    cin >> z_str[1]; 
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please input the third string [max.29 characters]:" << endl;
    cin >> z_str[2]; 
    cout << endl << endl;


    cout << "First string is:" << endl;
    cout << z_str[0] << endl << endl;

    cout << "Second string is" << endl;
    cout << z_str[1] << endl << endl;

    cout << "Third string is:" << endl;
    cout << z_str[2] << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I do compile this code with g++ in Linux Ubuntu and run the code I get an segmentation fault, when the program comes to the printing of the `char`strings into the CLI.

Terminal Output:

```
Please input the first string:
string1

Please input the second string:
string2

Please input the third string:
string3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

Now, If I compile the same code with g++/MingW in Windows 10 everything works as it should in the PowerShell:

```
Please input the first string:
string1

Please input the second string:
string2

Please input the third string:
string3


First string is:
string1

Second string is
string2

Third string is:
string3
```

---

- Why am I getting an Segmentation Fault with g++ in Linux Ubuntu, but not with g++/MingW in Windows, when printing a char string in C++?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You have an off by one error.  Your for loop is `for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)` but it should be `for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)` since the array has 3 elements.  With it as it is now `z_str[2]` has not been initialized.

Comment: TBH in the 21st century we'd use `std::array<std::string,3>`. It trivially prevents this problem.

Comment: Yep.  No use for raw arrays or `new` since 2011.

Comment: @MSalters I´m not allowed to use `std::array`.

Comment: I ran your program on Linux (Fedora 31), and it ran without error.

Comment: @eeijlar Just because it runs doesn't mean it's free of faults. That's one of the problems with undefined behavior: Sometime it seems to work, and in the next second it will crash or behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: I understood, which is why I wrote a comment instead of an answer. But I thought it useful to tell you that you're learning from someone who is a few decades behind the times.

Comment: Note that `new` doesn't return NULL if it fails, it throws an exception.

Comment: When behaviours change from system to system and from time to time, then this indicates that there is uninitialised data.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Great, thank you. How do I proof whether this exception is thrown?

Comment: Do you know what an exception is and how to catch one? If you don't catch it your program will terminate. It should throw a [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception or one derived from it like `std::bad_array_new_length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

will make you initialize `z_str[0]` and `z_str[1]`, but *not* `z_str[2]`.

Therefore you get undefined behavior (and the crash) when you use the uninitialized and indeterminate value in `z_str[2]`.

You need to increase the loop to iterate over all elements:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

---

There are better solutions to all of this, and the one I recommend is to use a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> z_str;
```

Now you don't need to do any dynamic allocation yourself, and all three strings in the array will be default constructed which means they will be empty (but valid) strings.

If you're not allowed to use either `std::array` nor `std::string`, there's still other ways to improve your program, for example using [range `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& str_ptr : z_str)
    str_ptr = new char[30];
```

The above loop is guaranteed to iterate over all elements of the array.

Comment: and to avoid this in future you can use either `sizeof` with raw array or `std::array`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Beginner mistake. I´m angry about that I did not catched it. Thank you for the helpful tips.